# React native's react-navigation is deleting modules

Tags: react-native

I am currently working with React Native and I want to use its navigation component. The documentation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/navigation.html) says I should install react-navigation module for using it, but when I install it

```
npm install react-navigation
```

the application stops working the moment it finishes installing. It seems it removes some modules; I get the following output:

```
added 16 packages, removed 1003 packages and updated 18 packages
```

Any idea why this is happening? How can this be fixed?

Comment: You need to upgrade your `npm` `npm install -g npm@latest`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What version of npm are you using? You may be experiencing this bug: https://github.com/npm/npm/issues/17379

Comment: Yep, the problem was npm. Thanks!